# How to set FocalLoss as the loss function used in YOLOv8?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, yolov8

Is there any functions or CLI i can use directly to set the loss function? or i need to edit the source code?

I look through the YOLOv8 Docs and did not see any direct way to make it.

I also try to edit source code in `utils/loss.py` as the [Doc](https://docs.ultralytics.com/reference/utils/loss/#ultralytics.utils.loss.VarifocalLoss.forward) said so:

> Wraps focal loss around existing loss_fcn(), i.e. criteria = FocalLoss(nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(), gamma=1.5).

but i dont know where and how specifically should i add this?

i would appreciate it for any answer that could help me.